# Change variable value for each variable in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

Suppose we have a list `variables` with the variables `[a, b, c]`. The code shall check if the variable value is a of type string with the text `"None"`. The variable value shall be updated to `""` if true. Using a for loop, I would write:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
variables = [a, b, c]

for i in range(len(variables)):
    variables[i] = 55

print(variables)
print(a, b, c)
```

This outputs:

```
[55, 55, 55]
1 2 3
```

Why don't the variables update their value?

Comment: You don't have a list of variables. You have a list of *values*. Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: You need to update the list itself, not a single item of the list.

Comment: Related (the opposite problem, basically): [How to update a list of variables in python?](//stackoverflow.com/q/41398763)

Comment: @deceze Those duplicates certainly solve the OP's problem, but they do nothing to explain why the OP's code doesn't work. The OP specifically asked why the code doesn't work. I think this should be reopened. (I tried to find a better duplicate, but couldn't.)

Comment: @deceze Any objections to me reopening the question?

Answer (score 3):

All you are doing is overwriting the value of the local variable `variable`, not an element in `variables`. You'll need to iterate over the indices and assign to `variables[i]` directly:

```
for i, value in enumerate(variables):
    if value == "None":
        variables[i] = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

If I reproduce your example the variable "variable" will indeed update. However, the list of variables "variables" will not. Because you are not telling it to change.

There are several ways to change this. If this is a small list I would simply create a new list

```
variables = [1,2,3,4,"None",5,1,"foo","bar"]

new_variables = [0 if variable == "None" else variable for variable in variables]
```

Hope this helps!